# Can't retrieve object property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Currently, I'm trying to retrieve a particular property from a javascript object returned by mongoose.
I can see the property when printing the whole object, but when trying to use it, I get an undefined. Here's the code:

```
Match.findOne({id: match.id}, function (err, match) {
    console.log(match)
    console.log(typeof match)
    console.log(match.id)
    console.log(match.winner)
})
```

The output of that is:

```
{ _id: 552c7f2925efcbc88ccc55bf,
    id: 499142595,
    region: 'br',
    winner: 200,
    championsLose: [ 25, 96, 81, 113, 63 ],
    championsWin: [ 37, 238, 201, 268, 81 ] 
}
object
499142595
undefined
```

Even though the 'winner' property is clearly there.
Any ideas?

UPDATE: added more logging to the above code and results of it

Comment: Can you include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a fiddle or snippet?

Comment: ^ fiddle for mongdb/mongoose?

Comment: Perhaps you have a virtual defined on a model somewhere, and it's fooling you?

Comment: The problem is somewhere else; this code looks fine to me. I'd replace "match" with another variable name and see how that affects it because I think there might be a problem with a global that's referenced with the same name.

Comment: are you changing deleting match.winner afterwards? it reflects back

Comment: @A.B can hardcode the data in the post for the MCVE, though if it's a DB configuration issue then a fiddle wouldn't make sense (does mongoose use lazy-loading like hibernate?).

Comment: I'm not convinced the `console.log(match)` is outputting an object - that's why `match.winner` is undefined

Comment: The two `console.log` calls are really located right next to each other?

Comment: Yes, they are next to each other. I'll print the typeof in a sec, I'll update with the info. I tried changing the name of the key in mongo and printing again, but the issue persisted. Not sure how to make a fiddle of it :(

Comment: woot woot! cookies for @iccthedral The problem was in the model definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the issue wasn't in that piece of code, but in the Model definition. The variable name wasn't updated properly, so the old name was still being used there:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Match',{
    id: Number,
    region: String,
    championsWin: Array,
    championsLose: Array,
    winnerTeamId: Number
});
```

And the proper model should be:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Match',{
    id: Number,
    region: String,
    championsWin: Array,
    championsLose: Array,
    winner: Number
});
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It's odd that there are no quotes around the value of associated with the key "_id":

```
{ _id: 552c7f2925efcbc88ccc55bf, // should be --> "552c7f2925efcbc88ccc55bf" 
id: 499142595,
region: 'br',
winner: 200,
championsLose: [ 25, 96, 81, 113, 63 ],
championsWin: [ 37, 238, 201, 268, 81 ] 
}
```

This seems to indicate that it is not actually an object.  Which, of course, explains why `match.winner` is undefined.  I would do `console.log(typeof match)` and see what it says.

Comment: Nope, it's an `ObjectId` which overrides `toString`. Plus, even if so, your answer leads nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

console updates("Live Update") the last references if the object/property is change even after `console.log()`. i have recently got this pain using chrome

it might be the case

check this example in `chrome`, dont know how this problem behaves in node console or the tool you are using

```
obj = {a:"b",b:"c"};
console.log(obj);  // logs Object { b: "c" } not {a:"b",b:"c"}
delete obj.a;
console.log(obj);// logs Object { b: "c" }
```

you might have deleted the match.winner property later in the code. that seems to be the case only